# Adding a @Profile annotation to a component prevents ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider from finding the bean

Tags: spring, reflection, spring-profiles

I have an annotation `@LogProperty` that can be applied to fields.

```
package com.foo;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("myapp")
public class FooClass {
    @LogProperty
    private String foo = "bar";
...
```

And some code that is looking for `@ConfigurationProperties` annotations:

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(ConfigurationProperties.class));

Set<BeanDefinition> components = scanner.findCandidateComponents("com.foo");
for (BeanDefinition beanDefinition : components) {
    ...
    check-for-LogProperty-annotation-and-do-something()
    ...
```

This code is then triggered in the `run(String... args)` method of a `CommandLineRunner`

With this I'm able to e.g. log the field/value to the console.

```
myapp: foo=bar
```

But if I add an arbitrary `@Profile` annotation - regardless if active or inactive to the `FooClass` the scanning code from above does no longer find the annotated field.

Why does the `@Profile` annotation prevents it from being found? Is there a way to "fix" this?

If I debug the code, than the debugger stops at the `foo` field before the `CommandLineRunner` is triggered. So I suspect it could be found but it is discarded to prevent a problem with inactive beans?

Comment: I've switched to: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.reflections/reflections this works as expected - BUT - keep in mind that if you have a bean that is not active and e.g. try to load it from the application context, there will be an exception that you have to handle.